# Automatic backup not working in Laravel with Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backup

I'm trying to run backup using cron, i'm using spatie-laravel-backup it is working when i run it manually but when i run it using cron using this path on server:

```
/home/user/public_html && php artisan backup:run >> /home/user/logs 2>&1
```

and i'm getting this

```
/bin/bash: /home/user/public_html: Is a directory"
```

> kernel.php

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
     $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->at('10:00');
    }
```

Comment: try `cd /home/user/public_html && php artisan backup:run >> /home/user/logs 2>&1`

Comment: you want to run `Scheduler` or `backup` ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul: i want to run backup, will running scheduler run backup also?

Answer (score 0):

run scheduler from cron

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

```sh
* * * * * cd /home/user/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

then

you can use

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->at('10:00');
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have implemented your code but i'm not receiving any notification of cron, how can i enable logs to check the status of cron

Comment: `daily()->at('10:00')` you will get this

Comment: But in my case i don't receive any notification on mail when this cron run.

Comment: then problem with cron

Comment: i was receiving notification when using this path /home/user/public_html.